# How to check the System folders in windows programmatically using C/C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to check the System folders in windows programmatically using C/C++?

I want to check in my code the user selected folder is a System/Windows folder or not? I tried using the methods GetFileAttributesEx/GetFileAttributes, but it's not working. By default. All the windows folder has the attribute FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM set to true.

Comment: Check them for what exactly? If you want to see if you can write there, try and write there.

Comment: @Deanna, He wants to check if a folder selected by the user is a system folder or not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "system folders". Are you including "c:\Program Files\XYZ"? Or just `%WINDIR%` and children? If the latter just check `GetWindowsDirectory`.

Comment: I want to restrict, if the selected folder is windows or part of the windows folder.. C:\windows or c:\windows\abc\xmy etc

Comment: Also note that the System attribute doesn't actually means it's a "system file/folder" or an integral part of the OS. Nowadays, it just means that it has a desktop.ini that can be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows Vista and later) to get various special folders. You can see the types of folders at [KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You could use this to retrieve the paths of the folders you want to check for, and then compare those against the user input path.

Comment: If the file the user selected is C:\program Files\Test1\Test2\Test3 . The folder is C:\program Files.
In this case, I need check C:\program Files is part of the selected folder. I am concerned about the performance

Comment: Get the "true" Program Files folder during some initialization, then just compare the string against the user input location (up to the length of the checked path length). Try it first, then worry about performance.